# Using selectInput to determines what function to apply in r shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny page where a dropdown Input selection chooses a function to apply to a dataset (different plotting functions of my own creation).

I've tried defining and naming list of my desired functions.

```
soil_function_list = c(data.sum, texture.triangle.plot, compaction.plot, carbon.plot, percent.change.plot)

names(soil_function_list) = c("Data Table", "Texture Triangle", "Compaction Plot", "Carbon Plot", "Change Plot")
```

Then in the UI the selectInput function refers to these names:

```
    ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage(         
    title = "Title",
    tabPanel("Soil",
             selectInput("soilplottype", "Choose Plot Type", choices = names(soil_function_list)),
             mainPanel(plotOutput("soilplot"))),
    )
)
```

Then in the server I want the output to apply whichever function based on the input

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$soilplot = renderPlot({
    func = input$soilplottype
    soil_function_list$func(data)
    })


}
```

This is returning an error on my page that says "attempt to apply non-function", so I suspect the problem is in how I'm referring to my function library.

When I try to use these functions directly out of soil_function_list, it puts backwards tick marks, which works fine - for example:

```
soil_function_list$'Data Table'(data)
```

I'm not sure exactly what these mean or how to apply them in a shiny input framework. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `soil_function_list[[func]](data)`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you that worked perfectly! What does the double bracket signify, for future reference?

Comment: To get the component named `A` of a list `L` you can do `L$A` or `L[["A"]]`.